# Python - Joining Dataframes with multicolumns and simple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, multi-level

I am new to Python and need your help.

I have two dataframes that I need to join (or merge or concatenate?).

The first has multi level column names:

df1:

```
Station         New Station            
X                    125032            
Y                   6563255            
Z                      1500            
Sensor                    P           T
Category      Precipitation Temperature
Unit                   mm/d           C
Interpolation ConstantAfter      Linear
1979-10-01          0.16352    -4.00487
1979-10-02          0.67616    -4.54372
1979-10-03          0.41640    -5.32490
1979-10-04          0.10048    -5.02924
```

The second one is df2:

```
Category    Temperature  Precipitation
2015-06-11      1.35931        0.28088
2015-06-12      1.47636        1.07184
2015-06-13      4.32775        0.67992
2015-06-14      3.06252        7.99056
2015-06-15     -2.76417        0.00576
2015-06-16      1.82125        0.28592
```

for information:

```
df1.to_dict()={('New Station', '125032', '6563255', '1500', 'P', 
'Precipitation', 'mm/d', 'ConstantAfter'): {Timestamp('1979-10-01 
00:00:00'): 0.16352, Timestamp('1979-10-02 00:00:00'): 0.67615999999999998, 
Timestamp('1979-10-03 00:00:00'): 0.41639999999999999, Timestamp('1979-10-04 
00:00:00'): 0.10048}, ('New Station', '125032', '6563255', '1500', 'T', 
'Temperature', 'C', 'Linear'): {Timestamp('1979-10-01 00:00:00'): 
-4.0048699999999995, Timestamp('1979-10-02 00:00:00'): -4.5437199999999995, 
Timestamp('1979-10-03 00:00:00'): -5.3249000000000004, Timestamp('1979-10-04 
00:00:00'): -5.0292399999999997}}
```

My question: How can I combine both dataframes in one dataframe, making sure that the Temperature data will end up in the temperature column and the Precipitation data in the precipitation column? The final dataframe should have the multi level column names.

Thank you very much

Comment: I assume `df1` is printed out wrong? Because seems like "Precipitation" is one of the values of the column `New Station`

Comment: Please output df1.to_dict() to the question.